# Looking for matching data in two workbooks of Excel, and format the matching results over a large data set

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a problem in Excel, in which I have to compare data in two separate workbooks, and look for matching pieces of information over several columns - as the time stamp in row A isn't an exact match in both workbooks I need to rely on the data points from the other columns out to column G - and format the rows in which a match is found in a certain colour.

I could do this manually, but due to the amount of rows numbering into 5 figures, I think VBA seems the best way to do this. Having only basic programming knowledge, I am struggling to see the correct way to do this with VBA.

Here is what I have tried so far, and I will also include the error shown when I run the code.

I am aware I said that more than row A is needed to make the comparison, but I am not sure on how to apply the rules to a matrix over columns and rows.

```
Sub vbax_53997_Compare_Two_Ranges()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wb1ws1, wb2ws2
    Dim blnSame As Boolean

    wb1ws1 = Workbooks("Copy_of_data.xlsm").Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("A1:A63").Value
    wb2ws2 = Workbooks("Copy_of_data_to_be_compared.xlsm").Worksheets("Archive").Range("A1:A23067").Value

    For i = LBound(wb1ws1) To UBound(wb1ws1)
        If wb1ws1(i, 1) = wb2ws2(i, 1) Then
            blnSame = True
        End If
    Next i

    If blnSame = True Then
        Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 3  'Set Color to Red'
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the error when I run the code;

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

I have no doubt its an easy fix and I could maybe do a nested vlookup/if statement, but taking longer in the short term to find a solution will probably be a benefit to automate the process in the long term.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have now run out of ideas.

Comment: If you want to compare columns other than `A`, can you provide what your comparison criteria is? and a sample of your worksheets

Comment: Zac, thank you for the response. The criteria would be to match a floating point number in column 'E' and a mixture of numerals and text in  column 'D', and only text in column 'C'. I am not sure the other cloumns will be an exact match so those three should be enough. I'm also unable to post any of the data here, apologies as I know that would make things easier.